# Vb.net Save which nodes were expanded in TreeView

Tags: vb.net, treeview, nodes, expand

I am creating a form in VB.net that contains a TreeView. This TreeView is populated with expandable parent nodes and corresponding child nodes. When the user runs the program, they can expand any nodes they want. Is there a way to programmatically save which nodes were expanded so that next time the form is loaded, those nodes remain expanded? I don't necessarily need coded examples (although they can be useful), just a general idea of the commands/controls/logic to use in the program. Thank you in advance!

Comment: There are a few ways. `MySettings`, save out to a file using binaryformatter, a database it's up to you how you want to save this data and retrieve it back.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not specific to a programming problem rather a recommendation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some basic ideas to guide your implementation:

Create a List to keep track of the nodes that are currently expanded:

```
Private _ExpandedNodeList As New List(Of String)
```

Set-up two event handlers to track the AfterCollapse and AfterExpand events of the TreeView - these happen when a user opens/ closes different parts of the tree. The trick here is that the event handlers just add and remove the Node's tag value which is some string you've set on the node when you built the tree.

```
Private Sub TreeView_AfterCollapse(sender As Object, e As TreeViewEventArgs) Handles TreeView.AfterCollapse
    If _ExpandedNodeList.Contains(e.Node.Tag.ToString) Then
        _ExpandedNodeList.Remove(e.Node.Tag.ToString)
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub TreeView_AfterExpand(sender As Object, e As TreeViewEventArgs) Handles TreeView.AfterExpand
    If Not _ExpandedNodeList.Contains(e.Node.Tag.ToString) Then
        _ExpandedNodeList.Add(e.Node.Tag.ToString)
    End If
End Sub
```

Now, let's assume that you have a point in the application where you need to restore the TreeView to a particular state. You can recurse the nodes in the TreeView and call Expand on the ones that are in your list.

My implementation looks like this:

```
Private Sub ShowVisibleNodes()
    Dim Node As TreeNode

    For Each ExpandedChildNodeName As String In _ExpandedNodeList
        For Each RootNode As TreeNode In TreeView.Nodes
            Node = NodeFromTagName(ExpandedChildNodeName, RootNode)
            If Node IsNot Nothing Then
                Node.Expand()
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub
Private Function NodeFromTagName(ByVal NodeTagName As String, NodeToSearch As TreeNode) As TreeNode
    Dim NextNode As TreeNode

    'check input node
    If NodeToSearch.Tag IsNot Nothing Then
        If NodeToSearch.Tag.Equals(NodeTagName) Then
            Return NodeToSearch
        End If
    End If

    'check child nodes and recurse on intermediary nodes
    For Each Node As TreeNode In NodeToSearch.Nodes
        If Node.Tag IsNot Nothing Then
            If Node.Tag.Equals(NodeTagName) Then
                Return Node
            End If
            NextNode = NodeFromTagName(NodeTagName, Node)
            If NextNode IsNot Nothing Then
                Return NextNode
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Return Nothing

End Function
```

Note this code isn't guaranteed to work simply by dropping it in your application.

At least, you need to think carefully about building your tree and whether or not you set a value on the Tag for each TreeNode.

Hopefully this will get you started.

Comment: Wow that's great thanks! And when I when I build my `ExpandedNodesList`, will this save and be available the next time the user starts the application?

Comment: You can definitely save the List but you have to do it yourself. For example, when the application closes you can write it out to a text file. Or take a look into the System.Runtime.Serialization namespace.

Comment: I guess the downvote here is because I didn't interpret 'save' as save to file, but interpreted 'save' as 'keep safe somewhere'? Vive le pedantry, huh!

Comment: Okay great, I figured it would have to be written to a text file. (by the way, I don't have enough reputation to vote). Whoever voted, please share the reason the answer isn't comprehensive, I'd be interested to know if I missed something.

Comment: @Robin just giving something out isn't constructive when the OP clearly doesn't have anything to show us what they have attempted. We don't condone just writing code out for them, rather help on specific issues. If people continue to do this then it can become a problem as we are not a code writing service. `I don't necessarily need coded examples (although they can be useful), just a general idea of the commands/controls/logic to use in the program` with this in mind, ***a little comment would suffice*** as it would give him something to look into.

Comment: @AidanKehoe the reason for the downvote is because this shouldn't be an answer, the answer clearly doesn't explain how to ***save expanded nodes at all or reload them on load***, yet you accept the answer that clearly doesn't fit with the question in mind. How does the accepted solution solve your issue? Also you didn't know where to begin, with this in mind do you understand the accepted solution? `I figured it would have to be written to a text file` I mentioned this in my comment from above, how come you didn't ask any further questions, was that not helpful enough where to begin?

Comment: @zaggler thanks for explaining your downvote. Couple of comments - in the question there's no talk about closing the application, serializing settings, restarting the application, restoring settings from file etc. He could load and unload Form during runtime and need to restore from the list whilst the application, as a whole, is still running. I have an application that does something quite similar and shared snippets with the OP to help him along. I noted he can't just drop the code in his application so don't believe he is being spoon fed (nor was this his request).

Comment: `Is there a way to programmatically save which nodes were expanded so that next time the form is loaded, those nodes remain expanded?` I believe he did ask that. You mentioned `there's no talk about closing the application, serializing settings, restarting the application, restoring settings from file etc` I am just disagreeing that he clearly did.

Comment: @zaggler Thanks for your comment. I accepted the answer because it helped me with my current project. The recursive method of checking through the nodes to find the ones from the list to expand is something that I can use (after changes of course). Although in the answer she did not explicitly state how to save the nodes for reload, she did affirm my idea of printing them to a text file and loading them the next time. As a result, the complete answer (ie including the comments) can be used to solve my problem... continued...

Comment: ... keep in mind I didn't ask for a complete solution (and she didn't give me one). As for whether I understood the solution, the answer is simple: I did. The current version of the project does not use a treeview, but a list view. I am just trying to convert from one to the other and was looking for some tips. I deemed that attaching my entire project would not be useful as there is nothing wrong with it, I am just trying to improve a small section. I don't see how any of my actions would lead you to believe I do not understand Robin's answer.